# Order fields in group by

Tags: mysql

Is any difference between:

```
select * from book group by id, name;
```

And

```
select * from book group by name, id;
```

And

```
select * from book group by Concat(name,":", id);
```

I try it, and have equal results.

Answer (score 0):

The last can be different in very specific cases. You need to be sure that your separator (":") cannot be present in name or id.

I don't see any differences in the first two queries.